# How to refer to child element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I know this is simple question but I am having trouble find a solution.. I have the following div structure..

```
<div id="myid">
  <div id="toggle">
    <img id="img" src="test_img.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div> 

<script>
$("#myid").mouseenter(function() {
$("#toggle").css("background-image", "url(test_img_b.jpg)");
$('#myid').children().animate({width: "0px", marginLeft: 0, opacity:0}, 'slow',   function() {$(this).remove();});
});
</script>
```

The code works fine, The issue is I do not want to refer "#toggle" div by its name, I want access through a child property or something similar. Because I will be having many block of "#myid" divs, and want the "#toggle" div animate depending on which div is hovered...

I hope I made my question clear.

Thank you - Malind

---

Thank you all, I have changed my scope according to your suggestions below and achieved what i wanted in the first place.

Regards
Malind

Comment: "many block of "#myid" divs"...that's not right, you should have unique id's. If you want to refer to multiple `div`s, use a class

Comment: Use class names instead of id values so you can repeat the same structure many times within the same document.  Then, when an event handler fires, use `$(this)` along with `.closest(".xxx")` or `.find(".xxx")` to find items above or below the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myid div")
```

That refers to ALL divs inside #mydiv

but really you're approaching it wrong. you can only have one unique id, but multiple classes. so select the class, not the id.

```
<div class="parent" id="myid">
  <div class="toggle">
    <img id="img" src="test_img.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div> 

<script>

$("#myid").mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.toggle', $this) //here you are setting the scope to the div you are entering
        .css("background-image", "url(test_img_b.jpg)")
        .animate({
            width: "0px", 
            marginLeft: 0, 
            opacity:0
         }, 'slow');
}), function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.toggle', $this)
        .animate({
             width: "0px", 
             marginLeft: 0, 
            opacity:0
        }, 'slow', function() {
             $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

you could do $('#myid').find('.toggle') but it's inefficient, and you should define your scope first, and then apply it. var $id = $('#myid'); $('.toggle', $id) and your scope can then be used over and over again without having to use .find() over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Id element must be unique so you can't have multiple elements with the same id - use class instead

```
<div class="myid">
  <div class="toggle">
    <img class="img" src="test_img.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(".myid").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find(".toggle").css("background-image", "url(test_img_b.jpg)");
    $(this).find('.img').animate({
        width: "0px",
        marginLeft: 0,
        opacity: 0
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/83qzR/)